# Is "the general public" redundant?

Tags: redundancy

Is "the general public" redundant? Or is it different from "the public"?

Comment: It's more specific in that it emphasizes the people you're talking about are just general, average, members of the public. Public beach-goers, for example, are only a subset of the "general public."

Comment: The English language is chock full of pleonasms, from *free gift* to *my own* to *false pretense*. If you want to pick on this one, your question would be strengthened if you [edit] it to include any initial research you've done in the matter.

Comment: Actually "the general public" is *less* specific, is the whole point. "The public" in many contexts is quite specific if you stop and think about it, and so we came up with "the general public" to distinguish that particular public from just absolutely everyone at large.

Comment: @jmrpink You should add that as an answer

Comment: @Kevin I normally would, but I always get downvoted by people because they think my answers aren't "scientific enough" or something like that. In comments you can only get upvoted or reported.

Comment: @jmrpink Don't let DVs get you down; we all receive them. A lot of people here will down vote an _answer_ to a question that shows no research. Apart from that, if you provide a reasoned answer that includes citation and sources, and put it into context, and you _still_ get DVs...brush it off as trollish behaviour.

Comment: @jmrpink The goal of Stack Exchange is to be an expert reference site. If you feel your answer helps with that, go for it. It takes 5 downvotes to cancel the points of one upvote to your answer. Support your answer in a reasonable fashion - personal experience, logical argument, examples in print, etc. In this particular case, I think personal experience of how the word ‘general’ is used would go a long way. There’s probably dictionary support as well.

Comment: @jmrpink Just a note, though: there’s a sense in which *the general public* excludes specialists where *the public* doesn’t, but there’s also a sense where *general* is used as an intensifier, setting the stage for Reg’s comment. I wouldn’t be surprised if the dictionary entry for *general* lists both kinds of usage.

Answer (score -1):

They are both common expressions that can convey the same  meaning. Note that public have also other usages:

It derives from the following connotation of ***[general](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/general)***:

> not limited to one class, field, product, service, etc.; miscellaneous:
>
> - the general public; general science.

***[The general public:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/general-public)***

> ordinary people, especially all the people who are not members of a particular organization or who do not have any special type of knowledge:
>
> - *This is a matter of great concern to the general public.*

***[The public:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/public)***

> all ordinary people:
>
> - The public has a right to know about this.

(Cambridge Dictionary)