# Different twist on "public" is or are?

Tags: verbs, nouns, grammatical-number

I just read this sentence:  "Note that 'public' have also other usages:"  Since in this use of "public," we're talking about the word itself & not the group it's referring to, shouldn't the verb be "has"?

([Is "the general public" redundant?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/458249/is-the-general-public-redundant#458249))

Comment: I'm a bit addled & have edited the verb to "has."

Comment: Are you asking if 'public' is singular or plural, or are you asking if ' ' public' ' is singular or plural?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your distinction.

Comment: Jerry, are you asking about the concept of a large group of people if it is plural (like a team) or  are you asking about an uninterpreted quoted sequence of letters, i.e. id it the _concept_ public that is plural, or is it the _word_ public (or really any single word at all)

Comment: The _word_ "public."  It's very clear from the context (provided in the link).  To clarify, he could've written "the word 'public' have also other usages."  Singular verb is the only thing that makes sense in that case.

Comment: Jerry, it is simple if it referring to a word. A word or multiword term in quotes is easily seen to be a single object, no matter what one may understand its meaning, and so is very simply singular. But it gets complicated for group concepts like teams or other things that are sets of individuals. In American English a team is usually singular, but in British English, often it can look like a singular but treated, as a plural as in "Arsenal _are_ winning the game".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right -- the verb must be "has". (Perhaps the writer meant to say "can have".) But "has also" is wrong too; it should be "also has".

Comment: Yes, the position of "also" indicated to me that the writer is not a native English speaker.